# cannot redirect with submit button within <form></form> tags

Tags: javascript, html

here is my js code

```
function fn(){
    alert('fn is being called');
    window.location ="www.google.com";
}
```

and here is my HTML. I can redirect when the HTML code

```
<div id="form">
    
      <button onclick="fn()">Submit</button>
    
</div>
```

but not when I include form tags like this

```
<div id="form">
    <form>
      <button onclick="fn()">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Why is this happening and what do I do to allow rediect with form tags?

Comment: The linked question answers the "why" pretty good. If you want to see how you can make your code work, without changing the HTML, then you can take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/fdm4p6bs/

Answer (score 1):

snippet updated to take care of event being depreciated

```js
function fn(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('fn is being called');
    window.location ="https://www.stackoverflow.com";
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="fn(event)">  
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but I get "event" is depreciated warning.

Comment: see updated snippet

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an alternative could be to use submit event on the `<form>`, but you probably run into security issues:

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location = 'https://www.google.com';
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working.